# How accurate is dog DNA testing?

Tags: dogs

I always rescue my dogs and recently (1 year ago) rescued one for my parents.  I've spent the last 12 months training her.  My dad is interested in knowing what breed she is, but I am skeptical on the DNA testing?  How accurate is it?

[This site says it's accurate, but only for determining the majority breed.](https://pets.webmd.com/dogs/features/dog-dna-testing#1)

> Sutter says such dog DNA tests can typically identify the majority breeds in a canine with great accuracy.

[This site says they are **fairly accurate**](https://dogbreedidentifier.com/dog-breed-testing-accuracy/)

> Dog DNA tests tend to be fairly accurate, although the quality of accuracy can vary depending on the tools used to asses dog genealogy and the sophistication of the laboratory used.

What can I do to make the test more accurate?  If my dad's dog has several breeds mixed in her (likely) how well can we identify those?